# CSS Triangle Hover Border Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using the following code

```
<ul id="leftNavUl"> 
    <li><a href="#">Colors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main Navigation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alerts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Data Tables</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like the hover to show a triangle / arrow at the end of each border to the right.

I have implemented the following code

```css
#leftNavUl li:hover{
    display: inline-block;lock;
    position: relative;
    background: #97cce9;
    padding: 15px; width:100%;}

#leftNavUl li:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #97cce9;
}
```

While the hover works, there is an extra triangle/arrow visible on the outside of the div.

[image: Image of Arrow / Border Triangle Issue]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should triger the after element only on the hover state.

Like `#leftNavUl li:hover:after`

And carfule you got a typo on you first class : display: inline-block;**lock;**

See code below : https://jsfiddle.net/d6h0xtup/2/

Comment: Non prob, don't forget to close your question. Bye !